# Good algorithm for marking a media file as listened

Tags: algorithm, user-experience, behavior

I'm writing a media player and want to mark media files as listened in order to filter them.

However, I'm lacking a good idea for when to mark a song/video as listened/watched.
Movies tends to create the largest problem. You might not watch the credits in the last two minutes, and you might skip around.

I guess I could track the total amount of played seconds, but this causes problems if the first half is watched twice for some reason. Keeping track of which parts of the movies has been played seems like a huge mess.

One of the best solutions I have come up with is to mark the movie/song as listened/watched if the use has played more than X seconds in the last 10% of the file. Then I would be reasonable to assume he has listened to most of it and/or listened/watched what he wanted.

However, all the solutions above are bad, and I would really like some input

Comment: How about creating a checkpoint at movieTotalDuration - AverageOfEndTitles, or at movieTotalDuration - 10 min, as no end title lasts more than 10 minutes. It's quite the same though with your 10% concept but simpler.

Comment: By filtering the files in the listened/not listened pattern, you will retrieve some stats (number of times a file was played within a period of time etc.). How do you want to use these stats ? The answer to this simple question will probably influence the _definition_ of a "listened file".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about another approach?

**If the user doesn't hit the next/prev/random button or closes in more than half of the media, then that file is listened/watched.** You may need to track the time watched, and taking care of time overlapping *(watching the first two minutes and then watching again the first one minute doesn't mean the user watched 3 minutes of your file).*

In my opinion, I'd play more with the skipping / closing feature, rather than checking if the user listened to X more than Y in the last 10%. You could anyway move to the last 10% and then the media would be marked as viewed.

However, my solution is not as accurate as it should be, and maybe there isn't one. Maybe you should look into the [UX site](https://ux.stackexchange.com/).